# android lay-out bitmap doesn't take full space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap

I have a bitmap I want to display, however it doesn't take all the place it has. I tried different types of layouts (Linear, Relative, Absolute, Constraint etc.) but none of them worked. I also tried to set width and height to 'match_parent'. It looks like [this](http://1drv.ms/u/s!Art57nRzmWuNnRNYW_Dc8LaSthxG) (the right image should take as much space as the left image).
Here is my XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <io.fotoapparat.view.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:rotation="90" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem, I only had to remove the `android:rotate="90"` and rotate the bitmap in the program itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you giving fix `height` and `width`?

You can use `LinearLayout` with 2 views, Give `android:layout_width=0dp` and `android:layout_weight=1`

It will work definitely.